# Does SQL Server read/write to/from a file when executing a simple query

Tags: sql-server

I have a very basic question about how SQL Server operates behind-the-scenes when executing a simple query like the one given below.

I am not talking about the execution plan that I know can be easily seen in SSMS but about file read/write that happens.

**Question**

When the below query executes then speaking in terms of *file* read/write operations, is it accurate to say that SQL Server is writing the final result set data to a file after reading some data from one or more files? Then SQL Server reads all data from the file into which it stored the final result set and returns that data.

```
SELECT ProductId, ProductName from Products
```

Comment: Short answer is no - sql server loads it in to memory. It's a matter in fact, sql server does everything in memory, other then storing intermediate results if you don't have enough of RAM.

Comment: @RuslanTolkachev, thanks. So, when I see in so many SQL Server books/blogs that mention file I/O, it's the file output(i.e. reading) that is occurring most of the times rather than file input (i.e. writing)?

Comment: when you use select, yes. Writes happen when you use Insert, update or delete etc. But it is really way more complicated then that, so I would suggest you would read documentation or a book - here is my favorite one https://www.apress.com/us/book/9781484219638

Comment: @RuslanTolkachev. thanks. I will check out that book.

Comment: _So, when I see in so many SQL Server books/blogs that mention file I/O, it's the file output(i.e. reading) that is occurring most of the times rather than file input (i.e. writing)_ When you make a SELECT from some table, you may run into I/O waits if DB is under heavy load and SQL server awaits some data directly from a file where table is stored. That is example of I/O file reading.

Answer (score 0):

A SELECT statement is nonprocedural; it does not state the exact steps that the database server should use to retrieve the requested data. This means that the database server must analyze the statement to determine the most efficient way to extract the requested data. This is referred to as optimizing the SELECT statement. The component that does this is called the query optimizer. The input to the optimizer consists of the query, the database schema (table and index definitions), and the database statistics. The output of the optimizer is a query execution plan, sometimes referred to as a query plan or just a plan. The contents of a query plan are described in more detail later in this topic.
The inputs and outputs of the query optimizer during optimization of a single SELECT statement are illustrated in the following diagram:

[image]

Processing a SELECT Statement
The basic steps that SQL Server uses to process a single SELECT statement include the following:

1. The parser scans the SELECT statement and breaks it into logical units such as keywords, expressions, operators, and identifiers.
2. A query tree, sometimes referred to as a sequence tree, is built describing the logical steps needed to transform the source data into the format required by the result set.
3. The query optimizer analyzes different ways the source tables can be accessed. It then selects the series of steps that returns the results fastest while using fewer resources. The query tree is updated to record this exact series of steps. The final, optimized version of the query tree is called the execution plan.
4. The relational engine starts executing the execution plan. As the steps that require data from the base tables are processed, the relational engine requests that the storage engine pass up data from the rowsets requested from the relational engine.
5. The relational engine processes the data returned from the storage engine into the format defined for the result set and returns the result set to the client.

Answer to you main question is it accurate to say that SQL Server is writing the final result set data to a file after reading some data from one or more files? in plain english: No.